# Cannot see ntfs-3g mounted drive files in Finder, but can in Terminal

Tags: finder, filesystem, ntfs

I use Macports and installed ntfs-3g @2017.3.23 with:

```
sudo port install ntfs-3g
```

I'm able to mount drives with:

```
sudo /opt/local/bin/ntfs-3g /dev/disk2s1 /Volumes/NTFS -olocal -oallow_other
```

However, when I browse the drive, I can't see any files.  I can see folders fine, but none of the files.

Yet I can see the files fine using `ls` etc. from Terminal.  The colors of the files (and folders) are yellow, which is unusual.  I haven't yet been able to decipher what this means, but here is my LSCOLORS for completeness (I think it's set by [bash-it](https://github.com/Bash-it/bash-it/blob/master/lib/appearance.bash)).

```
$ echo $LSCOLORS
Gxfxcxdxdxegedabagacad
```

How can I fix ntfs-mounted volumes to make files visible to Finder?

I'm running MacOS 10.14.3.

**Update**: I also tried using homebrew to install ntfs-3g, as documented at https://github.com/osxfuse/osxfuse/wiki/NTFS-3G, but same result.